# Understanding nibbles & encoding using owasp EnDe tool?

Tags: encoding, owasp

I'm using owasp EnDe web-based tool to understand nibbles and encoding in general. I'm testing a sample input which is `abcd`.

Now, the results of encoding it based upon first nibble and second nibble is given
as `36,1,36,2,36,3,36,4,37,7,37,8,37,9,37,A` and `6,31,6,32,6,33,6,34,7,37,7,38,7,39,7,61` respectively.

A simple representation in hex of above sample input is `61 62 63 64 77 78 79 7a`.

Should nibble 1 and nibble 2 in simple terms would be mean LSB nibble and MSB nibble respectively. Can someone explain how it relates to the use in this tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the code that performs the encoding it seems to work on the hex strings of the ASCII codes instead of taking the nibble of the ASCII code. So for you example of "abcd" and the 1 nibble encoding it works as follows.

'a' -> 0x61 -> '61'
First nibble of '61' is '6', with '6' -> 0x36 -> '36'
So 'a' ends up being encoded as %%361

'b' -> 0x62 -> '62'
First nibble of '62' is '6' and again will be '36'.
So 'b' ends up being encoded as %%362

....

I am not sure where this encoding is documented, perhaps you can try Google.

You can find the function that performs the encodings at https://github.com/EnDe/EnDe/blob/master/EnDe.js#L982

Comment: can you explain how did you converted 6' -> 0x36 -> '36' ?

Comment: So when you look up the ASCII code of the character '6' it will be 36 in hex. If we convert this to a hex string we get '36'.

Comment: for better explanation please see this link http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31602/understanding-nibbles-encoding-using-owasp-ende-tool